# select multiple discontinuous strings of charcacters (words) in a pdf

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

In a word document or similar, pressing down Ctrl allows selecting several words for batch treatment, so that one can ulteriorly for example copy all of them at once.

I'd like to know how to proceed to obtain similar results in a pdf document.

I am using the software Nitro Pro in Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can't make a discontinuous selection in any PDF viewer I've tried, including *PDF-XChange* and *Sumatra*, as well, nor by opening the PDF directly in MS *Word* or in LibreOffice *Writer*. But here are two work-arounds:

- Select *all* text in the document in *Nitro*, copy it and paste it into *Word* as text. You can then select multiple words while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
- If you need to select words in a *rectangular area* of text, place the mouse at one corner of the rectangle and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the free *Sumatra* PDF viewer, or <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the free *PDF-XChange Viewer*, while dragging the mouse. There is probably a similar way to do so in *Nitro*, but I could not find the key combo online.